# Boost log not showing named scope in shared object code

Tags: c++11, logging, boost

I'm using boost log (v1.71) to try and write logs. Our architecture involves a set of dynamically loaded shared objects, and I'm having trouble using the named scope attribute in the shared objects.

I am setting up a global logger in one of our support util libraries, which has logger.hh and logger.cxx:

```
//logger.hh

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
// etc.

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<trivial::severity_level>)

#define LOG_TRACE BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), trace)
// etc...
```

and

```
//logger.cxx

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, src::severity_logger_mt<trivial::severity_level>)
{
  src::severity_logger_mt<trivial::severity_level> lg;
  lg.add_attribute("Scope", boost::log::attributes::named_scope());
  return lg;
}
```

These get built into a shared library, linked at compile time to the main application and the dynamically loaded plugins. In the main application I'm initialising the logger:

```
//main.cxx
#include "logger.hh"

int main()
{
  logging::formatter fmt = expr::stream
     << expr::format_named_scope("Scope", keywords::format = "%n") << " - " << expr::message;

  logging::add_console_log(std::clog, keywords::format = fmt);

  BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE("main");
  LOG_WARNING << "test log";

  // Main code continues, including dynamically loading plugin shared objects.
}
```

Finally in the shared object plugin, linked to the util library:

```
//plugin.cxx

void Activity()
{
  BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE("Activity");
  LOG_WARNING << "activity log";
}
```

I have heavily paraphrased a lot of this, but hopefully all the key ingredients are here. Currently the output for running the program looks like:

```
main - test log
 - activity log
```

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to get the named scopes working? I appreciate that the use case here is unusual, but I would prefer to keep the single global logger shared between the whole program.

Using gcc 4.8.3, on RHEL7.

Comment: Make sure you're linking with shared libraries of Boost.Log. If this doesn't help, please provide a minimal compilable repro.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem, and do not seem to need to link against the shared libraries. We might swap to the shared libraries at some point, but for now as our code is functional as-is we will leave it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by adding a BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE macro call into the support shared object library. No other change seemed to be required. I don't particularly understand why this fixed the issue, but it has.

Comment: This is why I suggested you link with shared libraries of Boost.Log. Static libraries are only supported if you use Boost.Log in a single module (shared library or executable). Boost.Log maintains a number of singletons internally, so when you link statically in multiple modules the singletons get duplicated and you may get any kind of misbehavior.

Comment: Yes, I'll bear this in mind. We will likely switch soon.